# Oracle and H2 number data type incompatibility

Tags: spring, oracle, h2, flyway, in-memory-database

I am using Flyway for my Spring boot app (working with Oracle DB). I have a new script which will create a table with a number field, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ENGINEER (
    ...
    SALARY NUMBER(*, 2),
    ...
);
```

I want to debug the app with H2 database and it will run the script. H2 documentation says that NUMBER(precision, scale) is a valid data type but seems that it does not support * for precision as Oracle. So that I cannot debug it with H2, when I run the script cannot be run successfully:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-21 18:19:47.026 ERROR 25932 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration <file-name>.sql failed
-------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42001
Error Code : 42001
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "                                                        
                       
                                                        
CREATE TABLE ENGINEER(
    ...
    SALARY NUMBER(*, 2),
    ...
)"; expected "long"; SQL statement:

CREATE TABLE ENGINEER(
    ...
    SALARY NUMBER(*, 2),
    ...
) [42001-200]
Location   : sql/db/migration/v04/<file-name>.sql 
Line       : 1
```

Is there any way to do so that I can keep the migration script like above but still able to debug with H2 anytime I want?

Thanks

Comment: You can enable H2 web console. Pls follow: [H2 web console hrlp](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/h2-web-console.html). you can create h2 db with oracle mode like `jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=Oracle`

Comment: H2 doesn't accept `NUMBER(*, 2)` regardless of compatibility mode. Compatibility modes provide only very limited compatibility.